# Action sheet not opaque

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

For some reason the top half of the my action sheet is not opaque. I have created the view and action sheet using the code below:

```
//allocate the view
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                             initWithTitle:nil
                             delegate:self
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                             destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                             otherButtonTitles:@"Take a Picture",@"Select a Picture",nil];
popupQuery.delegate= self;
[popupQuery setOpaque:NO]; 
popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
[popupQuery showInView:self.tabBarController.view];
[popupQuery release];
```

I then tried to fix the problem by setting the opacity of the underlying view with the code below, but that didn't help either.

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor: color];
    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];
```

Any suggestions? The top half of the action sheet is a dark grey.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the overlay above the actual buttons (the top half of the screen), as in the screen at the left side of this image?

[alt text http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/art/ui_modalexamples.jpg](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/art/ui_modalexamples.jpg)

That's not supposed to be opaque. Is there some particular reason why it needs to be in your application? If you *do* need full coverage, perhaps a [modal view controller](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/ModalViews/ModalViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH11-SW7), rather than an action sheet, would be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the actionSheetStyle `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent` could help.